# laravel query filter array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've been trying to do this mysql equivalent in laravel:
SELECT * FROM `toys` WHERE type_id In (1,2,3)

here is my Controller code:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $type = (new Type)->newQuery();

if($request->has('type_id')){
        $type->whereIn('type_id',$request->type_id));
    }

    return $type->paginate(10);
}
```

The idea is to be able to query data from db in URL:
localhost/toyslist?type_id=1,2,3

Been getting Invalid argument supplied foreach()

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use explode to convert a string into Array

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $type = (new Type)->newQuery();

if($request->has('type_id')){
        $typeArray = explode(",",$request->type_id)
        $type->whereIn('type_id',$typeArray ));
    }

    return $type->paginate(10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I had been trying implode and wasn't working but EXPLODE works!

Comment: Although you solved this better you use another table for this and save one record in one column for searching and sorting